# Как выполнить действие по кнопке при свернутой форме c#

Tags: c#

Как сделать какое либо действие на клавишу ESC если программа свернута?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать WinApi функции.

1. Импортируем либы:

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
   public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);`
   ```
2. Добавляем поле в класс, которое будет хранить ссылку на хотекй

   ```
   const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
   ```
3. Регистрируем хоткей

   ```
   // Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
   // Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
   // ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
   RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 6, (int) Keys.F12);
   ```
4. Ловим нажатые кнопки:

   ```
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
   {                
       if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID) 
       {                   
           // My hotkey has been typed

           // Do what you want here
           // ...
       }
       base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
   ```

Взял отсюда:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413172/capture-a-keyboard-keypress-in-the-background

Comment: Ответ-ссылка -- это плохо, пнятненько?

Comment: @andreycha, хорошо, учту.