# Как сделать что бы кнопка на форме нажималась с клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня возникла проблема, мне нужно что бы кнопка нажималась сразу как только я нажму указанный символ на клавиатуре. 
Мой код:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

bool press = false;

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if ((textBox1.Text == "0") || (press))
        textBox1.Clear();

    press = false;
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + b.Text;        
}

private void button1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Char ch0 = '0';
    if (e.KeyChar == ch0)
    {
        if ((textBox1.Text == "0") || (press))
            textBox1.Clear();

        press = false;
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + b.Text;
    }
}

private void button2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Char ch1 = '1';
    if (e.KeyChar == ch1)
    {
        if ((textBox1.Text == "0") || (press))
           textBox1.Clear();

       press = false;
       Button b = (Button)sender;
       textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + b.Text;

    }
}
```

Нажатие на кнопку происходит только после выделения кнопки, но мне нужно что бы сразу, хотелось бы куда то запихнуть 
button.Focus();  
что бы при нажатии на кнопку на клавиатуре сразу выделяло нужную кнопку и нажимало на неё, это бы исправило ошибку. 
 Помогите  если знаете как это провернуть, или каким либо другим способом сделать что бы кнопку нажимало сразу.

Comment: Мне кажется, что тебе нужно использовать WinApi. Вот пример : http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562753/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-c/ в противном случае тебе придется делать велосипед. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: Хотя, можно попробовать, событие KeyPress повесить на главную форму, и уже в обработчике анализировать, на какую кнопку нужно назвать и вызывать соотвествующие обработчике событий.

Comment: Не нужно вам фокус перекидывать. У вас есть два события от пользователя: клик на конкретном батоне и нажатие на конкретную кнопку, при которых должно выполняться одно и тоже действие. Действие выносим в отдельный метод, который и вызываем при обработке этих событий. А как перехватить нажатие клавиш на уровне всей формы читайте тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554844/198316, там оба ответа рабочие, выберите какой вам больше подходит