# Блокировка совпадающих комбинаций клавиш в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте, есть задание : по нажатию клавиши `F10`, форма должна закрываться. Вопрос в том,как сделать так,чтобы похожие комбинации типа  `X+F10` или `Пробел+F10` эту форму не закрывали? Например, с `CRTL,ALT и SHIFT` я сделал, но как заблокировать все остальные? Помогите пожалуйста.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F10&&Control.ModifierKeys==Keys.None) this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то есть такое блокирование не возможно/не имеет смыла?

Comment: Хорошо,я понял,спасибо большое)

Comment: тогда перенесу в ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одновременное нажатие на клавиши регистрируется только для клавиш-модификаторов <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Для всех остальных - одновременное нажатие обрабатывается контроллером как последовательное. Поэтому фактически <kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> на самом деле <kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>F10</kbd> или <kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>.

Заблокировать такое можно только отслеживая последовательности нажатий на клавиши. Причем, в зависимости от разводки контактов клавиш клавиатуры, как последовательность нажатий может обрабатываться разное количество одновременно нажатых клавиш. На одной из старых механических клавиатур у меня получалось ловить последовательности до 8 клавиш, на современной пленочной - получилось максимум 3 и то не для любых клавиш.

В целом решение возможно, но имеет ли смысл решать уже вам.

Для регистрации последовательности, заводите буфер нужной длины, и нужные шаблоны последовательностей. После этого каждую нажатую клавишу проверяете подходит ли она к одному из шаблонов, если да, кладете ее в буфер и ждете нажатия следующей, если нет - очищаете буфер и кладете в него только что полученную клавишу. Повторять до совпадения с шаблоном.

Этот вариант не критичен к "одновременному" нажатию, интервал между нажатиями может быть любым. единственное - таким способом не получится обрабатывать одиночные нажатия на клавиши-модификаторы <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> и клавиши-переключатели <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, <kbd>ScrolLock</kbd>, <kbd>NumLock</kbd>. Эти клавиши надо ловить специальными способами.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону свойства KeyPreview.
вот это обработка нажатий на f4 и на alt

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F4&&e.Alt) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Тест");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Извините,разобраться как это мне поможет не получилось,может поподробнее объяснить,пожалуйста

Answer (score -1):

Можно так же обратится к возможностям WinApi и тогда приложение сможет анализировать комбинации кнопок, если оно даже не активно.

Вот тут пример:

[Как выполнить действие по кнопке при свернутой форме c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562753/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5-c/562755#562755)